# License alternative for linux

Tags: linux, licensing, license-key

there were many methods to validate software in windows system specifically validating the 
for example :

In windows operating system we used to validate software by storing key value at windows registry file the process would be as

> software starts --> license key --> browse and update license key(.key
>   file) -->whenever the software starts the license key was validated
>   with specific key value stored in registry key

The above process is common in windows operating system,what were the alternatives can be used for linux operating systems for an specific tool

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linux, it's common practice (as defined by [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)) to create a configuration file or configuration file in /etc. For example `/etc/myapp.conf`. It's up to you what format to use. License keys are often stored in this file/directory. This method requires root user access to configure the application and licence key.

The alternative approach it to keep a licence key for each user. The standard is to create a configuration directory in the user's home directory. The directory name begins with a "." (period) so that it doesn't list in a normal `ls` command. For example "/home/myuser/.myapp/config.properties". Again, the license key could be written here.

The later method would allow the software to be installed by the package managers (RPM/APT) and then the license to be prompted for when a user tries to use the software. Of course, the software would be licensed on a per-user basis.

Comment: whats the main diff b/w lsb and fhs friend?which suits the best

Comment: I corrected the answer to just reference FHS as the LSB spec depends on FHS - http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/execenvfhs.html